# Writing data to text file using sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to transfer data from table to a text file.I m trying to use bcp utility and xp_cmdshell.but the export is not successful.

If i execute below query its working fine.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT CONTRACT_NUMBER,BODY,SYNOPSIS,2,0 FROM AMPWEBAPP_TEST_DB..TM_DONOT_PUBLISH_TEXT_GRAPHIC_COMMENTS WHERE SYNOPSIS IS NOT NULL AND BODY IS NOT NULL" queryout "C:\bcptest.txt" -c -T -S'
```

But i want to append a value in where condition. Below is my query, its not working.

```
DECLARE @ACC VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ACC='12121'

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT CONTRACT_NUMBER,BODY,SYNOPSIS,2,0 FROM AMPWEBAPP_TEST_DB..TM_DONOT_PUBLISH_TEXT_GRAPHIC_COMMENTS WHERE SYNOPSIS IS NOT NULL AND BODY IS NOT NULL AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER='+@ACC+'" queryout "C:\bcptest.txt" -c -T -S'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess ACCOUNT_NUMBER is a `varchar` field in this case you should embrace `12121` with quotas as it is a `varchar` constant so:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT CONTRACT_NUMBER,BODY,SYNOPSIS,2,0 FROM AMPWEBAPP_TEST_DB..TM_DONOT_PUBLISH_TEXT_GRAPHIC_COMMENTS WHERE SYNOPSIS IS NOT NULL AND BODY IS NOT NULL AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER='''+@ACC+'''" queryout "C:\bcptest.txt" -c -T -S'
```